# How will ERC721 tokenUri update on Opensea?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have deployed a smart contract on Rinkeby network. I am trying to return the tokenUri based on a boolean as below:

```
function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    override
    returns (string memory)
{
    require(_exists(tokenId), "Token URI query for nonexistent token!");
    if(revealed == true) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(BASE_URI, "/", Strings.toString(tokenId), ".json"));
    } else {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(BASE_URI, DEFAULT_METADATA));
    }
}
```

The above code works fine. I can query the token URI on etherscan and see desired output. However the same is not reflecting on Opensea. Opensea is showing the old image always. I have a function using which I can set revealed bool value.

I have waited for 24 hrs to see if Opensea updates but it does not. What can be the issue?

Comment: Were you able to get it's solution? You are basically updating the tokenURI after minting an ERC721 token right?

Comment: @YashGarg Yes. There are multiple issues that can cause this. In my case it was simply point number 2 below.
1. Opensea sometimes lags and is very slow + you might have not clicked on refresh metadata button on Opensea.
2. The json of metadata is not as per standards.
3. The json file path returned by tokenUri function is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can move to Opensea and there you can find a update Metadata option.
So if your blockchain code works fine then it will automatically update to the current URI.

[You have the refresh metadata button here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25RBB.png)